# Maximum consecutive repeats of a substring in a given string using string library in Java

Tags: java, string, function, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to find the maximum consecutive repeats of a substring in a given string. I'm using substring(), equals(), and length() methods from the String library. However, I don't get the correct result. Here's my code-

```
 public static int maxRepeats(String dna) {
        int max = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dna.length() - 3; i++) {
            String s = dna.substring(i, i + 3);
            if (s.equals("CAG")) {
                count++;
                i += 2;
            }
            if (!s.equals("CAG")) {
                max = count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Let for example `dna= "CAGCAGCAGTTCAGCAGCAGCAGTTCAGCAGCAG"`

Then, max consecutive repeats of substring `"CAG"` = 4 ---> expected output

But for this substring or any substring, this is the result I get-

```
max repeats = 0
```

Would be grateful if someone pointed out where am I wrong :-)

Comment: Could you please add the input and expected output to the question?

Comment: sure just a minute @pallavirichhariya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code was you are not saving the max value properly . It was getting overridden to value 0 when ever the substring is not equal to "CAG". Instead you only need to set the value of count=0 in else condition and not max =0. Check this code. It should work for you

```
int max = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dna.length() - 3; i++) {
     String s = dna.substring(i, i + 3);
      if (s.equals("CAG")) {
          count++;
          i += 2;
       } else {
          count=0;
       }
            
       if (count>max) {
          max = count;
        }
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help you . Happy Learning!

Comment: this  solution returns 4 for "CAG", "CAGCAGCAGTTCAGCAGCAGCAGTTCAGCAGCAGCAGCAG", where as the answer is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing for not equal to `CAG` and it is not necessary, resulting in you not saving the max correctly.  Also, it is not necessary to check for count on each iteration.

```
public static int maxRepeats(String dna) {
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= dna.length() - 3; i++) {
        String s = dna.substring(i, i + 3);
        if (s.equals("CAG")) {
            count++;
            i += 2;
        } else {
            // only check max when CAG is not present.
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
            // but reset counter regardless.
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return Math.max(max,count);
}
```

Another alternative is to use regular expressions.

```
public static int maxRepeats(String dna) {
    // find the longest repeats of CAG
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(CAG)*").matcher(dna);
    int longest = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        String f = m.group();
        if (f.length() > longest) {
            longest = f.length();
        }
    }
    // the longest string must be divisible by 3 so...
    return longest/3;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :-) Will learn about regular expressions and then implement this code too!

Comment: the loop solution returns 4 for "CAG", "CAGCAGCAGTTCAGCAGCAGCAGTTCAGCAGCAGCAGCAG", where as the answer is 5.

Comment: @prashant You're correct,  I believe it is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Method 1:

```
/**
* @param pattern string being searched
* @param text string being searched in
* @return max number of times pattern can be self-appended and remains a 
* substring of text
*/
int maxRepeats(String pattern, String text) {
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= text.length() - pattern.length()) {
        String s = text.substring(i, i + pattern.length());
        if (s.equals(pattern)) {
            count++;
            i += pattern.length();
        } else {
            max = Math.max(max, count);
            count = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return Math.max(max, count);
}
```

Method 2:

```
int maxRepeats(String pattern, String text) {
    String s = pattern;
    int max = 0;
    while (s.length() <= text.length()) {
        if (text.contains(s)) {
            max++;
            s += pattern;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```